# How to declare CONST when it doesn't exist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, constants

So in short, I have a module that I want to reuse multiple time on a page. In this module, I had a global const of an event name. The problem occurs at the declaration of the second usage of this module since the constant has already been declared. However, I can't move it into if/else since scoping will make the constant unable to be used elsewhere. What should I do?

Some simple code for my problem:

**Module:**

```
const THIS_IS_MY_EVENT = 'thisIsMyEvent';

// extra code down here
```

**Page:** (I use twig engine to include file but I don't think it's related)

```
<script src="/path/to/file.js">
<script src="/path/to/file.js">
```

This sure won't work in my case:

```
if (typeof (THIS_IS_MY_EVENT) == undefined) {
    const .... //this will limit the scope of my const
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understood you correct, what about storing the const in a constants file and import it in each module u like ?

Comment: @YarinDekel how is that different? You still going to import the constant file twice into the page since you are importing the module twice. The workaround I see in your case is setting all constant in 1 file and directly importing it into the page itself. But it's kind of a mess, IMHO

Comment: @TreeNguyen You might misunderstand how importing works. Modules are cached, with the internal code only running once.

Comment: Or just use *var*, ;-)

Comment: @MattWay sorry not really that. I think my terminology is wrong. In my case, module = a piece of reusable code. It is not a class in any sense and there is not importing nor exporting. By using twig, it's basically a copy paste file into file. So the "module" I wrote got inserted twice into the same page

Comment: @RobG thought of that. Hate myself. Cry :'(

Comment: Yes, it totally defeats the purpose of *const* and isn't really a solution so much as a work around until you get to implement T.J. Crowder's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> So in short, I have a module that I want to reuse multiple time on a page.

That sounds like the real problem to solve. Instead, import the module once, *use* a function within it twice. Modules generally shouldn't *do* anything on import (other than a bit of setup), only later when requested. That way, the global parts of the module will run once, creating the global `const` (but it shouldn't be a global, it should be an exported `const` from the module), and you won't have the problem.

But conditionally creating a global constant is an interesting problem. If you really want a global, you can use `Object.defineProperty` to create it on `window` with `writable: false`. (This isn't quite the same. Properties on `window` [the global object] are globals, but `const` creates globals that *aren't* properties of `window`. Still, probably close enough.)

Example:

```js
"use strict";
if (typeof THIS_DOESNT_EXIST === "undefined") {
  Object.defineProperty(window, "THIS_DOESNT_EXIST", {
    value: "foo",
    writable: false,     // false is the default
    configurable: false, // these are just for emphasis,
    enumerable: true     // or false, your call
  });
}
console.log(THIS_DOESNT_EXIST);
THIS_DOESNT_EXIST = 42;
console.log(THIS_DOESNT_EXIST);
```

Comment: I really need it to go to global since I use this constant to fire up event and listen to it.

Comment: @TreeNguyen - That doesn't follow. If you make proper use of modules, you don't need **any** globals.

Comment: hi, as I mentioned in my comment up there. I believe my terminology is wrong indeed. In my case, module = a piece of reusable code. It is not a class in any sense and there is not importing nor exporting. By using twig, it's basically a copy paste file into file. So the "module" I wrote got inserted twice into the same page. And in both of them, the code is a bit different.

Comment: @TreeNguyen - In your question, you show loading the **same** file twice, so the code can't be different. If you're really loading two separate files that both might create the same constant, don't. Instead, have a single file that creates the constant that you load only once (before either [or both] of the other files). Or take a step back and switch to using proper modules; these issues are why modules were created.

Comment: You are correct. After stating the problem to you, I do realize that the problem is messy and not any solution will clean up the mess. I will step back and look for a more proper way